# How to Personalize window behavior in odoo 8 livechat

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, livechat, odoo-website

How to Personalize window behavior in Odoo 8

Goals for now are:

- add fields asking visitors Name, Email and Concern, As you can see at first image "A" the customer name is "Visitor"
- change visitors name base on his/her Name input
- change the design (background color, font, etc)

I already search on odoo documentation but no tutorials for Live Chat customization.

[image: Admin View]

[image: Customer View]

TIA

Comment: What exactly do you want to personalize? Please be specific by possibly posting a screenshot

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas, sorry, I am referring to Odoo live chat.  I already added a screenshot. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

The appearance and the behaviour of the `live_chat` window is defined in the files `addons/im_chat/static/src/js/im_chat.js`, `addons/im_chat/static/src/xml/im_chat.xml` and `addons/im_livechat/static/src/js/im_livechat.js`

Depending on your needs your will have to modify these files. For the needs you have outlined in your question you have to:

> 1) add fields asking visitors Name, Email and Concern, As you can see
>   at first image "A" the customer name is "Visitor"

You have to modify the `send_welcome_message` function on the `im_livechat.js` in order for you to send a custom initial message and you have to change the `im_chat.Conversation_message_bubble` template in order to give each "text bubble" a different look (for example to insert a textbox asking for user's info)

> 2) change visitors name base on his/her Name input

When you collect your data, the user's name is saved in the variable `defaultUsername` in `im_livechat.js`, you will have to set it there

> 3) change the design (background color, font, etc)

All of this can happen from changing the template with the name = `im_chat.Conversation_message_bubble` from the `im_chat.xml` file accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeDaramouskas, i will try your answer then ill get back to accept

Comment: Hi @GeorgeDaramouskas, will it be okay to apply my changes directly to im_chat.js and im_livechat.js ?

Comment: That is up to you @AlejandroAlainIII. There should not be an issue

Comment: I want to change it using my own created module but its not working when i am including something in im_livechat.js, but it works in im_chat.js